# Why would a fairy want to marry a human?

Tags: fantasy-races

I'm currently plotting a fantasy story inspired by celtic fairy mythology. In celtic folklore, there are many fairy lovers, that is, romantic or sexual relationships between humans and fairies. Usually these relationships are forced. Either a human male forces a fairy female to be his wife, for example by taking away and hiding her swan feathers or seal skin. Or a fairy male forces himself on a human girl he encounters on his grounds or lures her with promises of love only to kill her.

In my story, I would like a female fairy to willingly enter into a romantic relationship with a human male (i.e. "marry" him), without guile or force on either part. But the problem I have is motivating why a fairy would want to live with a human partner. So:

**Why would a fairy want to marry a human?**

I am intimately familiar with celtic folklore and the fairies there have no inherent interest in human-fairy romantic relationships. My question therefore does not stem from a lack of research, and you don't need to be familiar with celtic folklore to answer my question. Let me explain: Fairies in celtic mythology are not human. They either exemplify abstract moral principles (and reward politeness, helpfulness, diligence, and so on) or have the alien mind of forces of nature, that interact with humans in the same way an animal or storm would. The motivation I seek must be in tune with the fairy's non-human character. I can therefore rephrase the question a bit:

**Why would the personification of a moral principle or the personification of an aspect of nature enter into a romantic relationship (or something that appears as such) with a human?**

*[I understand](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that questions about actions of individual characters, character building, and elements of plot are off topic on this site. My question, though, is not concerned with the actions of an individual character or the building of the personality of an individual character, but rather the general motivations of a species in my world. Your answer, therefore, shouldn't apply to one random individual fairy (and, for example, suggest that unlike other fairies this specific fairy might find fairies unattractive and humans attractive), but must explain either a general human-mating behavior pattern in fairies or point out certain characteristics in fairies that under the right circumstances lead a fairy to wanting to marry a human.*

Comment: You self answer your question: she is in love with the human (you have the very same example in LoTR with an elf marrying a human).

Comment: The fairy queen can be quite predatory, especially with boys named Tom

Comment: You stated explicitly that one needs to know Celtic folklore to answer your question. I don't think there is anything wrong with this in principal, many questions require background knowledge. The issue is though that a) there won't be many people here that know Celtic folklore in detail and b) Celtic folklore is a difficult topic in general. We know very little about them, they are a super diverse group of people stretching from Turkey to Ireland and one could argue their time also stretches over 1000 years

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. The way this site works is that people ask questions here when they run into **problems** regarding their world-building. "I am building a world but I cannot figure out how...". You do not really appear to have a problem here. Instead you say *Please research Celtic folklore for me and come up with a reason for a fairy and human forming a permanent union*. At the risk of sounding crass... of you have done this already, what is it that prevents **you** from coming up with that reason? And if you have **not** researched Celtic folklore, start there. :-)

Comment: PS: (not enough space) Most of what we claim to know about them and their culture are very recent inventions, often not dating back more than 200 years. They also mixed heavily with Romans and Germans and Greeks and more. Could you maybe at least give the sources/time span/region of what you consider to be fitting Celtic folklore / the world you want to build on?

Comment: I'm afraid this question could be answered in a million different ways. You don't need us to come up with ideas which are essentially plot points. If you want political motivations then you need to provide a lot more information. Perhaps the fairy just wants someone to pick things off high shelves?

Comment: I have attempted to explain how my question (a) does not require familiarity with celtic folklore, (b) pertains to a specific worldbuilding problem, and (c) cannot be answered in more ways than any other question on this site. I hope you will consider to reopen. Thank you.

Comment: @L.Dutch Nowhere do I say that the fairy is in love with the human. I say that she enters into a romantic relationship with him. To me, as a psychologist, the technical term "romantic relationship" only differentiates a relationship with "moderate to high intensity levels of intimacy, commitment, and passion" (as one definition goes) from other kinds of relationships (e.g. with parents, friends, coworkers etc.). A marriage of convenience (and without love) is a romantic relationship as well.